# Postman proxy - "stop capturing" what does it mean?

Tags: networking, jvm, postman, server-administration

I am using Postman proxy for "capturing request and cookies"

Do I understand it correctly:
Pressing "Capture requests" starts the proxy service.
Pressing "Stop capturing requests" stops the service or ... only unchains the intercepting/logging hook but the proxy service still works on??
I hope for the first option.

Also the messages after starting and stopping the capturing is a bit confusing "Proxy connected", "Proxy disconnected". Is it still running and only the Postman UI gets connected or disconnected?

PS
Actually the question is a bit related to programming and at least JVM behavior. I am running my java client application through a Postman proxy i.e. launching it with the command line like:

$ java -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=5555 myClient.jar

Then when I press "stop capturing requests" (stop proxy?) in Postman the client still works ok ...(I think moving automatically to the original server port?) is that JVM proxy selector magic or what?

Comment: This is not about programming, so it's off-topic here. There's a server administration sister site.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: You are right. But the answer (if you know it) is shorter than the redirection.

Comment: That doesn't matter; if we allowed any questions with potentially short answers here, we could just forget about trying to stay on-topic all together. "Which of these three wines goes well with venison" has a very short answer, too. (also, your comment also takes longer than asking a question on the server site, so kindly do that.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes Sir.   But by "sister site" do you mean some other portal I should repost the question. Or only tagging this post with "server-administration" - what I just have done.

Comment: Actually the question is a bit related to programming and at least JVM behavior.
I am running my java client application through a Postman proxy i.e. in the command line I am launching it like $ java -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=5555 ....
Then when I press "stop capturing requests" (stop proxy?) the client still works ok ...(I think moving to the original server port) is that JVM proxy selector magic or what?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks